# Dynamic Field References in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, dynamic-soql, reference

[I recently posted a question regarding a component I am building.](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/216605/creating-generic-related-list-lightning-component) That post has the code I will be referencing.

I have been able to make the necessary edits and now I return an sObject to the `serverResult` attribute, which is also listed as an object type now.

My question is this: how can I pull the correct information out of serverResult? Here is the method I am currently using:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.serverResult}" var="item">
            <li class="slds-item">
                <div class="slds-tile slds-tile--board">
                    <h3 class="slds-truncate"><a href="{! '#/sObject/' + item.Id}"> {!v.objectName}: {!item.Name}</a>  </h3>
                    <div class="slds-tile__detail slds-text-body--small">

                        <p>{!v.field1Label}: {!item.field1} <br/>
                        {!v.field2Label}: {!item.field1} <br/>
                        {!v.field3Label}: {!item.field1}</p> <br/>                            

                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </aura:iteration>
```

I can get item.id and item.name to work perfectly because I can do a direct reference to them. The whole idea of this component is that I can use it again on a different object, and thus a different set of field references. Hence why the fields are named field1, etc.

The problem is that `{!item.field1}` won't return anything because (obviously) field1 is not an actual field name on that object. How can I make [field1] dynamic so I can have it actually look for the field I defined in the field1 attribute?

I tried `<p>{!v.field1Label}: "{!item."+field1+"}" <br/>` 
and
`<p>{!v.field1Label}: <ui:outputText value="{!item.'+v.field1'"/> <br/>` but those are throwing an error.

Comment: There already exists a library that does this for you, You can refer it for ideas. https://github.com/mshanemc/PowerRelatedList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet here would be to use a custom apex class, create the contents of that class in your apex method and finally use that on your component.

So let's say you have a custom class as:

```
ServerResult {
    @auraenabled 
    public string field1Label{get;set;}
    @auraenabled 
    public string field1Value{get;set;}
    @auraenabled 
    public string field2Label{get;set;}
    @auraenabled 
    public string field2Value{get;set;}
}
```

You can define a server method where you can fetch data as required from different object, and then create a list of this custom class as below:

```
@auraenabled
public static List<ServerResult> getResults() {
    List<ServerResult> myrecList = new List<ServerResult>();
    // all your custom logic to fetch records and populate this list
    return myrecList;
}
```

Finally, in your JS controller where you call the aura apex method, you can have it retrieved as:

```
// all other codes
component.set("v.serverResult", response.getReturnValue());
```

Finally use as you are rendering it in your component.

Comment: Still he has to show fieldLabel:fieldValue pair right...  He's trying to create apex:releatedList VF implementation in SF.

Comment: The custom bean class can be extended for that purpose. Updated in my answer.

Comment: Forgive me if my understanding is incorrect, but I think that was exactly what I started with. I created a wrapper class named tileWrapper and returned that to a list attribute exactly the way you are showing. The problem I was having is that when I wanted to get that information into my aura:iteration, the fields were returning blank. I could not even get item.name to display. I switched to List<sObject> and suddenly I could get item.name to show. I thought it was a data type error or something?

Comment: @Chance So if you had a "name" variable in your wrapper class, you should have been able to use that. Note that the variable names accessed on the component/JS are case sensitive, so you may like to check on that front.

Comment: It certainly isn't an issue with case, as I copy pasted. and I just checked again. Could it maybe be that I need each of the lines in my wrapper class to have `@AuraEnabled` ?

Comment: Yes if you did not already have it in there. All variables in the class that you plan to use on the component need to be auraenabled.

Comment: Right you are. I have it working now. I have to have `@AuraEnabled` for each. That and I referenced the name incorrectly, so it seems to be working now. Thank you both!